# Unknown provider: $secProvider <- $sec <- videoPlayerModalCtrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to open YouTube video in my angular app. I got to know that I have to use $sec to open YouTube video in Angular after doing some research. So, I injected $secProvider in my App.Config as follow:

```
 movieApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$sceProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $sceProvider) {
```

and use $sec in controller as follow:

```
(function () {
angular
    .module('common.controllers') 
    .controller('videoPlayerModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', '$sec', 'url',
                                        function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, $sec,url) {  
        $scope.givenUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
            $scope.ok = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        };
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
}]);
```

}());

At the present, I got error message that said "Unknown provider: $secProvider <- $sec <- videoPlayerModalCtrl". Could you guys tell me what I am missing to get $sec work.

Thanks

Comment: typo.  it's `$sce`, not `$sec`.

Comment: Thanks Claies, you save my day.